# HMS FusedLocationProvider and HuaweiMap is not working

Tags: android, android-location, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-location-kit

I used this class to get current location of device for my map app. I'm using this with `GooglePlayServices` and its working fine, but I recently switched to `HMS` for Huawei devices if `GooglePlayServices` are not available on device. I replaced all `GooglePlayServices` classes with mirror objects from `HMS` imported lib and it compiled without errors. But as I call for current location, it will not return anything. No exception, no success or failure.

I did not receive callback to `onLocationResult()` or `catch()` block.
According to debugger last row called is `val task = lp.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this, Looper.getMainLooper())`

Anyone has this problem? This is clearly new issue. Testing this on `Huawei P40` where `GooglePlayServices` are **not** available.

Also HuaweiMap is not working in release mode. `getMapAsync()` will not return `onMapReady()` callback. It got stuck there. But if I switch debug mode, it is working correctly.

**UDPATE:**
HuaweiMap is working now. Updated proguard. But Location is still not working. It is not working even in debug mode.

Code:

```
private inner class LocationCbHua(val lp: com.huawei.hms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient,
                                      val onFailure: (()->Unit)? = null,
                                      val onSuccess: (GpsLocation)->Unit)
        : com.huawei.hms.location.LocationCallback() {

        init {
            val lr = com.huawei.hms.location.LocationRequest.create().apply {
                priority = com.huawei.hms.location.LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                interval = 200
            }
            val lsr = com.huawei.hms.location.LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().run {
//                setAlwaysShow(true)  // TEST
                addLocationRequest(lr)
                build()
            }
            val check = com.huawei.hms.location.LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity!!).checkLocationSettings(lsr)
            check.addOnCompleteListener {
                try {
                    check.getResultThrowException(com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException::class.java)
                    val task = lp.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this, Looper.getMainLooper())
                    task.addOnFailureListener {
                        onFailure?.invoke()
                    }
                } catch (e: com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException) {
                    when (e.statusCode) {
                        com.huawei.hms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED-> if(!locationResolutionAsked){
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                val re = e as com.huawei.hms.common.ResolvableApiException
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                re.startResolutionForResult(mainActivity, MainActivity.REQUEST_LOCATION_SETTINGS)
                                locationResolutionAsked = true
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                        com.huawei.hms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE->{
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            App.warn("Location is not available")
                            onFailure?.invoke()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun cancel(){
            lp.removeLocationUpdates(this)
            currLocCb = null
        }

        override fun onLocationResult(lr: com.huawei.hms.location.LocationResult) {
            cancel()
            val ll = lr.lastLocation
            onSuccess(GpsLocation(ll.longitude, ll.latitude))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, did you have a chance to checkout examples on Huawei's Codelabs GitHub?

Comment: Yes. It looks almost same as mine. But core functionality is the same.

Comment: 1. Did you set up store data location on Developer page? 2. Did you save your app's key fingerprint for release (optional for debug too)?

Comment: I generated SHA256 hash from my .keystore file used for signing APK. And added it to AppGallery. Idk what is that first part. I just downloaded `agconnect-services.json` from my project and placed it to resources similar to firebase google json.

Comment: Please look at this pages. Make sure you followed the instructions. 1. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSLocationKit/index.html (step 4) and this 2. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html (step 6).

Comment: Yep, I did that. I though I need some API key in meta-data inside AndroidManifest like GoogleMaps. I have project there also I updated certificate fingerprint (SHA256 hash). Without fingerprint I couldnt see anything in map even in debug mode. Now Map is perfectly fine in debug but I have white screen in release. onMapReady() is not called.

Comment: Make sure AppGallery has updated all apps and libs on your P40.

Comment: Everything is updated.

Comment: Could you make sure you declared right proguard rules for both libs - maps and location? https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/hms-map-integratingthehmssdk (last point 5) and https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/location-preparation (last point 3).

Comment: I put those lines to `proguard-rules.pro` file and Map is finally working on release. But location is still not working.

Comment: Also, you are using `check.addOnCompleteListener()`, could you use also `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener` and try catch them?

Comment: On my side it didn't show the dialog as well unless I change the permission of HMS Core app location to "Allow all the time"

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause is as follows:

After checkLocationSettings code was executed, an exception was catched during execution of code `check.getResultThrowException`. However, the catched error code is not `6 (RESOULTION_REQUIRED)`.

Therefore, code `com.huawei.hms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE` was directly executed to report `Location is not available` after code `com.huawei.hms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED-> if(!locationResolutionAsked)` was executed.

As a result, neither exception nor location result was obtained.  You are advised to add a code line at `when (e.statusCode)` to record error logs, and then continue error analysis.

Comment: Catch branch was never executed. I put log above `when()`. Last row was `val task = lp.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this, Looper.getMainLooper())`

Comment: You can use addOnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener instead of addOnCompleteListener, please try again, I see the source code, addOnCompleteListener will directly throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

Use OnSuccessListener instead of OnCompleteListener

```
   val check = com.huawei.hms.location.LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity!!).checkLocationSettings(lsr)
   check.addOnSuccessListener{
       lp.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this, Looper.getMainLooper())
   }
```

You can also check this post:

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201272177441270079&fid=0101187876626530001